# How to get child models (records) in one call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails 3.2.6 application. I have a `Status` model, an `Event` model and a `Photo` model.

**Event**

```
Has_many :statuses
```

**Status**

```
Belongs_to :event
Has_one :photo
```

**Photo**

```
Belongs_to :status
```

I want to get all status messages belonging to a selected event (this works fine) but
I also want to get the photo belonging to each status message. How can I do this?

This is how I get the status messages belonging to an event:

```
@event = Event.find_by_id (params[:event_id])
@event.statuses
```

How can I get the associated photo for each status message to in the output?
I have started it and I suppose I should do something like this? But that only get
the photos and does not "merge" them with respective status message.

```
@photos = @event.statuses.collect {|status| status.photo}
```

Comment: With merging I mean that the status message and it´s attached photo will be merged into the same output object. Not all statuses have photos.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to reduce queries you can do something like below

```
@statuses = Status.where(:event_id=>params[:event_id]).includes(:photo).all
```

then you will be able to access like this

```
@statuses.each do |status|
    status.event_id # access the status
    status.photo # access the photo
    # status.nil? will check whether photo is there or not
end
```

Comment: Will I get both the status data and the photo data in the same output object? @loken makwana Not all statuses have a photo.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this to select everything in one query:

```
@event = Event.where(:id => params[:event_id]).includes(:statuses => :photo).first
```

Note that without the chained `first` it will return an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not an `Event` model instance. Then you can do

```
@photos = @event.statuses.map(&:photo).compact
```

**EDIT**

OK noticed your comment about some statuses not having photos. IIRC (I don't have a way to check this right now), `includes` will do a LEFT JOIN (maybe it depends on the underlying DB adapter), returning statuses with and without photos, so you will have to either nil-check individual `status.photo` refs or use `compact` to filter out the nil objects from `@photos` like I did above, depending on your purpose.

Comment: Looking good. Will this get all statuses (with photo if present)?

Comment: This is what the `includes` part is for. It selects all the relevant DB fields in one query, so the second code snippet in my answer should not cause a requery.